# Access to fetch from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, cors

I set the cors module but it still getting this problem,this what i get in the browser console:
login:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
POST http://localhost:3001/login net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch.
this is my frontend:

```
    import React, {SyntheticEvent, useState} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

const Login = (props: { setName: (name: string) => void }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        });

        const content = await response.json();

        setRedirect(true);
        props.setName(content.name);
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/"/>;
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required
                   onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />

            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required
                   onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Login;

this is my backend:

const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const routes = require('./routes')
const cors = require("cors");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/passport-jwt', {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
})

const app = express()
app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3000'}))
require('./auth/auth')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(routes)

const PORT = 3001

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`App listening on ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Express documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

> credentials: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials CORS
> header. Set to true to pass the header, otherwise it is omitted.

Because you include the credentials in the request, in the backend, you need to add option "credentials" to pass the header. Replace :

```
app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3000'}))
```

by :

```
app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3000', credentials : true}));
```